# Solved: Is this a bug - [civicrm.files] variable

Tags: drupal, issues, ckeditor, drupal-multi-site

Drupal-7.54 , CiviCRM-4.7.16
Multi-site / Aegir platform.

On a clean Drupal+CiviCRM instal the autogenerated path for the [civicrm.files] variable in 'Settings - upload directories' differs from the URL path generated in 'Settings - Resource URL'.

In Settings- Upload Directories the civicrm.files variable is: var/aegir/platforms/platform_name/sites/***siteURL***/files/civicrm

In Settings- Resource URL the civicrm.files variable is: h t t p://siteURL/sites/***default***/files/civicrm/

The problem does not arise in a non-multi-site environment, where both paths point to 'sites/default/files/civicrm (as confirmed on the sandbox demo).

This also seems to affect the path to the files/civicrm/persist directory.

One effect of this seems to be on CKEditor: when the CKEditor configurator is used it creates files (e.g. crm-ckeditor-civimail.js) in the persist directory. But these files are ignored when CKEditor is used in Civimail (see [Solved: How do I allow all tags in CKeditor](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17220/how-do-i-allow-all-tags-in-ckeditor), and [4.7.15 breaks civimail styles and templates (fullPage doesn't help)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16641/4-7-15-breaks-civimail-styles-and-templates-fullpage-doesnt-help) and maybe [CiviMail template format in HTML not saving](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16536/civimail-template-format-in-html-not-saving)

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19303

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
A fix for multisites and Aegir setups will come out in CiviCRM 4.7.21.
See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-193

---

The fix for our problem ended up being somewhat multidimensional.

The patch in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19303 solved the issue of the autogenerated path for the [civicrm.files] variable in 'Settings - upload directories' differing from the URL path generated in 'Settings - Resource URL'.

Though the issue doesn't seem completely solved, the patch has very recently been merged https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9409

(There is a bit of a rabbit hole that leads to https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9053).

But this did not totally fix the problem for CKEditor as the CKEditor config file is being placed in the persist directory (instead of persist/contribute) and the persist directory kept returning  a 403 error. Until CRM-19303 is fixed we circumvented it by allowing the vhost to read the persist directory instead of persist/contribute. We temporarily patched hosting_civicrm to do this.

Aegir was also throwing some file permission errors when creating new sites, and appears to be a different issue, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2791953. We applied the patch which will likely get committed.

We had to enable the Aegir fix_permissions and fix_ownership modules for this, which are experimental, but somewhat necessary here.

For now you still need to manually run a Verify on the site after creating it.

Thanks to Kainuk (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/110/kainuk) for his pointer and to Guillaume Boudrias from praxis.coop (https://www.drupal.org/u/gboudrias) for going down the rabbit holes to fix the problem.